# Access Denied by ACLs for Operation: read, uid

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

**Error**:

> odoo.models: Access Denied by ACLs for operation: read, uid: 4, model: product.template, fields: activity_ids
> You do not have enough rights to access the fields "activity_ids" on Product Template (product.template). Please contact your system administrator."

Even when I wrote this in `model.access`, I still have the same issue:

> mail.access_mail_activity,access.mail.activity,mail.model_mail_activity,,1,1,1,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you somehow create an activity on the product template for a user, who has no read rights to that product template?

Or does the user trying to access `activity_ids` on this specific product template not have those rights?

The access rights of activities are bound to the access rights of the related document itself. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c23f0d5ae2870e5ab7637c37f5f37f9a33ef3bf4/addons/mail/models/mail_activity.py#L276-L316)

```py
    def _filter_access_rules_remaining(self, valid, operation, filter_access_rules_method):
        """ Return the subset of ``self`` for which ``operation`` is allowed.
        A custom implementation is done on activities as this document has some
        access rules and is based on related document for activities that are
        not covered by those rules.
        Access on activities are the following :
          * create: (``mail_post_access`` or write) right on related documents;
          * read: read rights on related documents;
          * write: access rule OR
                   (``mail_post_access`` or write) rights on related documents);
          * unlink: access rule OR
                    (``mail_post_access`` or write) rights on related documents);
        """
```

That topic is very complex, but i hope this still helps.

Additional info: Something similar was done with attachments (ir.attachment), but it's implemented in another way.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.
Haven’t created any activity on product template.

To give it direct access just modified ir.model.access but it does not work:

mail.access_mail_activity, access.mail.activity, mail.model_mail_activity ,, 1,1,1,1

maybe something else should be added?

Comment: Does the user has rights to `product.template`? Don't only look into `ir.model.access` but also into `ir.rule`. And if possible add the code to your question, where or when the error is raised. That could help me and others find more hints, what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The `activity_ids` field at `product.template` is related to the object called `mail.activity`. In order to check what has happened to the access right on that field, you can try to temporary disable all security rules attached to the object:

1. Make sure you activate debug mode.
2. Go to Setting -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Model.
3. Find `mail.activity` model then open it.
4. Click on `Access Rights` tab, print screen to remember existing rule, then uncheck all the rules.
5. Click on `Record Rules` tab and do the same as point 4.
6. Try again.